# How to Count plutus transactions?

Tags: plutus, cardano-db-sync, ledger

i'm connected to the cardano-db-sync, someone knows how to count the ammout of transactions that use plutus script?

i'm using two methods here

```
select block.epoch_no,  
count(distinct tx.id) as txs_in_epoch,
sum(case when script.type = 'plutus' then 1 else 0 end) as txs_on_plutus_contracts

from tx inner join block on block.id = tx.block_id 
left join redeemer on tx.id = redeemer.tx_id  
left join script on redeemer.script_hash = script.hash  
where epoch_no = 298
group by epoch_no
```

2. diff

```
count(distinct tx.id) as txs_on_plutus_contracts
from...
where script.type = 'plutus'
```